# Typo3 getTypoLink_URL creates wrong link after language change

Tags: php, module, typo3, realurl

I hope I can manage to explain this problem...

I have an T3-extension that handles shared content.

In this shared content, we have links (page-ids) that are defined and converted into something like /en/clients/contact, using

```
$cObj = t3lib_div::makeInstance('tslib_cObj');
$href = $cObj->getTypoLink_URL($linkValue); // $linkValue is an integer (e.g. 153)
```

This works fine - until I change the language on the page. Then, the last used URL kinda «sticks» and the language indicator isn't present in the URL anymore.

Means:

- call the german page -> works
- change to english -> works
- change back to german -> the english link is presented.

So the above link turns out like clients/contact (the leading slash is gone as well).

Oddly enough, I have a local installation of the same page where the problem doesn't occur. It's just on the page that's online.

I tried to find differences in the configuration, but there aren't any.

The only difference I could find so far is, that I use Typo3 v4.5.35 for the local installation and v4.7.17 for the online installation.

Any ideas???

Answer (score 0):

This was very odd... but, I found a solution.

Instead of using `$cObj->getTypoLink_URL($linkValue);` I'm using this:

```
$configurations['additionalParams'] = "&L=".(int)t3lib_div::_GP('L');
$configurations['returnLast'] = 'url'; // get it as URL
$configurations['parameter'] =  $linkValue;
$href = $cObject->typolink(NULL, $configurations);
```

It seems that when I created the $cObj, the L-Parameter got lost somewhere, somewhen. By adding it manually, the Link works as expected.